# How to determine that boost::asio::io_service has finished the task?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I need to build a thread pool with scheduling priorities: all running threads have the same priority in terms of CPU time and OS priority, but when it takes to pick the next task to complete, the one with the highest priority goes first.

I've decided to try the boost::asio as it has a thread pool that looks good.  I've looked over the [prioritized handlers example in the asio documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp) but I don't like it because it doesn't limit the number of threads, and I have to schedule the tasks manually. What I need is a fixed number of threads that would take tasks from a queue, so I could create the single pool in my application and then add tasks at any time during the application lifetime.

What would be sufficient is getting some notification from the asio::io_service when a task is finished; the handler of that notification could go and find the next task with the highest priority, and post it to the service.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why not just write a function that picks the task with highest priority and run it instantly? You could post several such functions to the asio:io_service.

Comment: @peper0 your idea is surprizingly simple, and it looks great! I wonder why I didn't have it myself. Thank you! Will try it soon.

Comment: I might miss something, but why can't you use for this purpose `wrapped_handler` from the aforementioned example? Just put your notification code at the end of the functor's `operator()`.